# python regular expressions format/ negative range

Tags: python, regex, format, range

I'm currently learning about pythons regular expressions but can't find a way to solve the following issues.
I want to insert a variable into my regex. I can do that comfortably with the "old" style using %.
However if I use format() and my regex contains a {} for the number of allowed occurrences, it gets problematic.
For example: `a = re.compile("[{0}]{1}[{1}]{1}".format(exp1, exp2))`
Is there some kind of work around?

Also i was wondering how you can have a negative range.
For example: `a = re.compile("[A]{1}[(-1)-4]{1}")`
Other post suggest something like `[-+]?`, but that matches too much.
I only want A-1, A0, A1, A2, A3 and A4 to be allowed.
I'd appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: ItIt is always complicated to have two questions together - in this case the first one was a duplicate. The answer to your second question is: Use an "OR" in regex:
`A(-1|[0-4])` should do the trick.
General hint: Check the online regex editor regex101, it allows you to write your own regex and try it on any data you like.

Comment: I really appreciate your reply. I was looking carefully through the other posts but seem to have missed the thread to the first question. Thank you very much for your help though.

Comment: You are welcome. Feel free to ask further questions but maybe stick to one question at a time ;-)